# How can I listen to the onFieldChange event in Odoo 16 using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-16

I would like to listen for the onChange event of a field in Odoo 16 using JavaScript. I have attempted the following code snippets, but they did not yield the desired results.

my_module/static/src/js/on_field_changes.js

```
odoo.define('my_module.on_field_changes', function (require) {
"use strict";

const fieldRegistry = require('web.field_registry');
const { FieldChar } = require('web.basic_fields');

const onchange_widget = FieldChar.extend({

    _onFieldChanged(ev) {
        console.log('=========  > > > > Hello')
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    },
});

fieldRegistry.add('onchange_widget', onchange_widget);  });
```

In form view:

```
<field name="father_name" widget="onchange_widget"/>
```

In manifest.py:

```
'assets': {
    'web.assets_backend': [
        'my_module/static/src/js/on_field_changes.js',
    ]
}
```

In addition, I have attempted several other code snippets, but unfortunately, none of them proved successful either.

Comment: What's the point on listen changes? Try making your code to be compatible with OWL components because your code it's targeting the legacy js widgets

Comment: @aekis.dev I need to return a dialog whenever a specific field is changed in Odoo's form view. since you cannot return a wizard on onchange event in Python, So I am trying to do it in JavaScript.

Comment: Mmm. That will be hard to accomplish. You will need to do everything by yourself since odoo doesn't let you manage this low level stuffs without a huge widgets overhaul